# Second dropdown menu based on value in first (html php mysqli)

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I have a MySQL database and am trying make a conditional dropdown menu ("Subcategory") show values based on the values in the first dropdown, ("Category").

This is a reference data table, so the parent ID of the subcategory should match the ref_data_id of the category.

The conditional list relies on the  value of the first dropdown box, and I have tried $_POST and $_GET to try to get the value from the first  object to use in my MySQLi query but neither seems to work.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php

                // connect to the database
                include("connectdb.php");

            ?>

            <html>    
            <!--First Dropdown Menu - CATEGORIES-->
                <div class="label">Select Category:</div>
                <select name ="Category_HTML">
                <option value = "">---Select---</option>
                    <?php
                    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `ref_data` WHERE Parent_ID IS NULL ;";
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt);
                    while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))   {
                            $description = $row['Description'];
                            $refdataID = $row['Ref_Data_ID'];
                            echo "<option value='$refdataID'> $description </option>"; 
                    }
                ?>
                </select>  

            <!--Second Dropdown Menu - Subcategory-->
                <div class="label">Select Subategory:</div>
                <select name="subcategory_HTML">
                <option value = "">---Select---</option>
                <?php
                    $idvalue = $_POST['Category_HTML'];
                    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `ref_data` WHERE Parent_ID = $idvalue;";
                    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $stmt);
                    while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                $description = $row['Description'];
                                $refdataID = $row['Ref_Data_ID'];
                                echo "<option value='$refdataID'> $description </option>";      
                    }
                ?>
                </select>


            </html>
```

Comment: This sounds like a front-end issue. Consider using JavaScript.

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Answer (score 0):

try to make an AJAX call when a value is select in the category list i.e

```
<select name ="Category_HTML" onchange="AJAX_CALL()"> 

 and populate the result in the 

<select name="subcategory_HTML">
```